# Символическая ссылка в qt

Tags: c++, qt, qfilesystemmodel

Возможно ли создать символическую ссылку в ФС средствами Qt?
Ссылки должны работать как на windows, так и на unix, при том, крайне важно иметь возможность ссылаться на директории.

Comment: Чем `QFile::link()` не устраивает?

Comment: можно средствами стандартной библиотеки с++17 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_symlink

Answer (score 0):

разве что запуском внешней программы

```
QProcess p;
#ifdef __linux__ 
    p.start("sh ln -s .....");
#elif _WIN32
    p.start("mklink ....");
#else
#endif
```